# Any way to make Applescript count "&" as a word?

Tags: applescript

When I tell Applescript to count the words of a string like "A & B" with the text item delimiters set to space, it returns 2.  It is not counting the ampersand as a word.  Is there any way to change that?  After all, "&" means "and", which does count as a word.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

```
set theString to "A & B"
set wordCount to do shell script "wc -w <<< " & quoted form of theString & " | tr -d ' '"
```

In this example, it returns: `3`

Answer (score 0):

This script uses the [Satimage.osax scripting addition.](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/downloads_companion_osaxen.html) After putting the Satimage.osax file in your folder /Library/ScriptingAdditions/Satimage.osax, you should be able to view its dictionary and all of its commands in ScriptEditor.app by going to menu item “Window/Library”

[Download Satimage Scripting Addition](http://www.satimage.fr/software/downloads/Satimage411.pkg)

```
set theString to "A & B"
set toExclude to {" "} as list -- Variable For Items To Be Removed From Your List In Line 4

set theWordCount to items of theString -- Returns The Items Of Your String As A List {"A", " ", "&", " ", "B"}

set resultList to exclude items toExclude from theWordCount -- Removes Specified Items From The List
set theWordCount to count items of resultList -- Returns 3 As Your Count

get theWordCount -- This Line Is Not Necessary And Can Be Removed
```